# Socket programming : sending packet on UDP (C++)

Tags: c++, c, sockets, networking, udp

I am trying to send a packet message (having a header and an array of data) in UDP.
I am at a preliminary stage using no data in the message, and i want to send this header, which is represented by a struct of struct and a nested enum.

Is there any other way to send data on UDP other then serializing said structs then constructing buffer data and sending them ? is there like a buffer routine in c , c++ socket programming that sends data packets

Comment: This is more vague than

Comment: You will send packets, but these packets will consist of raw byte data anyways. There is no builtin standard serialization for everything.

Comment: My question was, if you have a complex struct, is serializing it into a buffer is the only way to transmit it, or is there something like serializable of Java in c++

Comment: @user1895125: Yeah you have to do it yourself. But there are loads of tools to _help_, which is all `Serializable` really is.

Answer (score 0):

If your `struct` is byte-aligned and only uses POD types, you could pass the struct directly to `sendto()` without copying it to another buffer first, eg:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1) // or other platform-appropriate pack statement
struct myHdr
{
    uint8_t type;
    uint16_t len;
    //...
};
#pragma pack(pop)

myHdr hdr;
hdr.type = ...;
hdr.len = ...;
...

send(fd, &hdr, sizeof(hdr), 0);
```

But this practice does tend to get frowned upon.  And it is not very helpful once you start adding data.  But you can allocate a buffer and use a byte-aligned `struct` to fill the buffer, at least:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1) // or other platform-appropriate pack statement
struct myHdr
{
    uint8_t type;
    uint16_t len;
    //...
};
#pragma pack(pop)

uint8_t buffer[65535];
myHdr *hdr = (myHdr*) &buffer[0];
hdr->type = ...;
hdr->len = ...;
...
// fill in &buffer[sizeof(myHdr)] onwards as needed

send(fd, buffer, sizeof(myHdr)+..., 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what the `sendmsg()` function is for. It provides a 'gather-write' facility. You provide it with one or more (maybe zero or more) buffer addresses and lengths and it gathers them all together into a single send.

But you shouldn't use `struct`s as network protocols. Use network protocols as network protocols. Define yourself an application protocol in octets, and write yourself a library to pack and unpack your structs into/from an octet stream.

Or use XDR or its cognates.